# Change colors of pixel in rescaled black and white picture

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, canvas, colors

Given a black and white picture, which the user created. I want to add a color function.
Since the size of the picture he created may vary, I fixed the height in PHP and drew the original image:

```
    //Get img Data
    $.ajax({
        url: "/_app/request.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        data: ({msg : message}),
        success: function(data){
             $('#qroriginal').attr("src",data)
        }
    });
```

Inside the create function I used:

```
$img= imagescale($img , 200, 200);
```

and then changed the color using a color picker as input:

```
    //in front and back are the new rgb color values
    var c=$('#prev');
    var ctx = c[0].getContext("2d");
    var img=$('#original');

    ctx.drawImage(img[0],0 ,0);

    var imgData= ctx.getImageData(0,0, c[0].width, c[0].height);
    //change colors
    var i;
    for (i = 0 ; i<imgData.data.length;i+=4){
        if(imgData.data[i] > 200){
            imgData.data[i] = front[0]; 
            imgData.data[i+1] = front[1]; 
            imgData.data[i+2] = front[2]; 
        }
        else if(imgData.data[i] < 50){
            imgData.data[i] = back[0];
            imgData.data[i+1] = back[1]; 
            imgData.data[i+2] = back[2]; 
            imgData.data[i+3] = imgData.data[i+3];
        }
```

Now the problem: Without rescaling, the rgb values of black are already between 245-255. But if i rescaled it. I get some values which are between 100-150. So I dont't know if it is a white or black pixel.
I was thinking about changing the create function in PHP or writing a better filter in javascript, looking at the neighbour pixel.

Comment: Can't you do it the other way around, recolour and then scale?  Scaling is normally considered a destructive process (data that once was there is lost) so it's normally left to the last thing you do when working with images.

Comment: That would be an option, which will work for sure, but i want to do it client based. Otherwise I have to send a request to the server everytime a new color option was selected.

Comment: You could keep a copy of the original image on the server and apply any colour changes to that, then scale it before sending it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values between 100-150 are not complete black/white hence they are not close to 255/0. I would prefer to take a factor (5% or 10%) by which I will add into the pixel value after scaling. This would produce much relevant
result.

Comment: Sorry just be clear. So after rescaling i should check the pixel of the image and manipulate them, before returning?. But isn't there the same problem, when a pixel has a color which is not complete black/white?

Comment: When you scale the image, the pixel colors appear more lighter (a small image has clear boundaries but the scaled one has light black/gray pixels around the boundary.) If you set a factor of 5% to increase the color towards more darker side...it will appear more clearly as if it appear in smaller size.